# How does recursion keep track of answer?

Tags: python, recursion

I am trying out this challenge on Hackerrank: https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/the-power-sum/problem

There are 2 ways to solving the problem:

- recursion
- dynamic programming

**my issue:** I don't understand a part of the recursion solution. I don't understand how it is able to keep track of "answer" when it is constantly set to zero.

**sample input:**

29

2

**correct answer:** 2

**Sample output:**

```
cur 0
cur 0
cur 0
cur 0
the 0
cur 0
the 0
the 0
cur 0
cur 0
the 0
the 0
cur 0
the 0
cur 0
the 0
the 0
cur 0
cur 0
a match:
4 9 16 the 1
the 1
cur 0
the 1
a match:
4 25 the 2
the 2
cur 0
cur 0
the 0
the 2
cur 0
the 2
cur 0
the 2
```

**the code:**

```
import math
import os
import random
import re
import sys

def powerSum(x, n, value):
    s = sum (v**n for v in value)
    if s == x:
        print "a match:"
        for v in value:
            print v**n,
        return 1
    else:
        v = value[-1] + 1 if value else 1
        answer = 0
        print "cur", answer
        while s + v**n <= x:
            answer += powerSum(x, n, value+[v])
            v += 1
            print "the", answer
    return answer


if __name__ == '__main__':
    fptr = open(os.environ['OUTPUT_PATH'], 'w')

    x = int(raw_input())

    n = int(raw_input())

    value = []

    result = powerSum(x, n, value)

    fptr.write(str(result) + '\n')

    fptr.close()
```

Comment: `answer` isn't being assigned `0` every time `powerSum` is being run. Whenever you call `powerSum` from within `powerSum`, you're basically creating a new, separate `answer` that has no ties to the original `answer`.

Comment: wow how am i to wrap my head around such inception. does this apply to all recursion? might you be able to point me to resources where i can read up more on this?

Comment: This is not just recursion, anything involving a change of scope. [This notebook has a nice walkthrough.](http://nbviewer.jupyter.org/github/rasbt/python_reference/blob/master/tutorials/scope_resolution_legb_rule.ipynb)

Comment: Recursive functions work exactly like non-recursive functions – it's the same as if you had two completely different functions, both with a local variable called "answer", and called one from the other.

Answer (score 1):

The code you have provided in the question implements recursion in a slightly tangled way. That is all. Consider a little bit different version of the same code:

```
def powerSum(x, n, value):

    answer = 0

    s = sum(v**n for v in value)
    # base case
    if s == x:
        answer = 1
    # recursive case
    else:
        v = value[-1] + 1 if value else 1
        while s + v**n <= x:
            answer += powerSum(x, n, value+[v])
            v += 1

    return answer
```